# Script no se ejecuta

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pyinstaller, exe

Tengo un problema, realice un script con python 3.8, usando selenium para la automatizacion del navegador de google
dicho script lo pase a arhivo .exe, usando pyinstaller, ahora mi pregunta es porque solo funciona en la pc donde lo cree y cuando intento ejecutarlo en algun otro ordenador, no hace absolutamente nada

cabe mencionar que use en un primer momento pyinstaller --windowed --onefile
igual no me funciono, luego intente con auto-py-to-exe y el resultado fue el mismo

Comment: Cómo fue que definiste el lugar donde buscar chromedriver en tu script? En otro ordenador se ubica en el mismo lugar?

Comment: No, no se ubican en el mismo lugar, puede ser eso que afecte?

Comment: Yo creo que sí, siempre y cuando no hayas incluido chromedriver como binario en tu configuración de pyinstaller para tu script. Otra opción sería asumir que chromedriver se encuentra en el PATH de cada ordenador.